# Using addClass in jQuery UI Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using [jQuery UI Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/) for navigation purpose. I want that when one item is clicked it's background color should change (to show active state) and when user clicks on other item then the new item's color should change and the previous one's color should revert back to original.

I used addClass for that but somehow it's not working, let me know where I'm doing wrong.

[Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PaHXs/5/)

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu" class="nav">              
   <li><a href="#" >Item 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Item 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.selected{
    color:red;
}
```

jQuery

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#menu" ).menu();
  });
  $(function () {
  $(".nav a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().addClass('selected'). // <li>
      siblings().removeClass('selected');
  });
  });
```

Comment: You must use `background-color` instead of `color`.

Comment: Yes, got it, stupid mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply style on the anchor instead of li. since anchor's inherited red color gets overridden by `.ui-widget-content a`

```
.selected a {
    color:red;
}
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2jgTz/)

With background color:-

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6YdXK/)

Comment: Oops, just had to use `background-color` instead of `color`.

Comment: If I do ".selected a {color:inherited;}" then it will take priority over ".ui-widget-content a" right ??

Comment: @ChankeyPathak suit yourself. This has both the options working.. :)

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh not really, it is `inherit`. But then you will have to have both the style rules like http://jsfiddle.net/BNWBX/.

Comment: @PSL yes that ".selected {color:red;}" is already there.. thanks for confirming. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('selected');
$(this).parent().addClass('selected');

.selected{
    color:red;
}

.selected a {
    color:inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at http://jsfiddle.net/PaHXs/8/

May i know is this your requirement or not.

I did change in

```
.selected{
    background-color:red;
}
```